# .gitignore in cakephp: ignore everything but files which are named empty

Tags: git, cakephp, tmp

the cakephp project is using so called empty files.
empty files are literally named empty and had no information inside.Their only purpose: Empty directories can be commited by versionising via git.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with the /app/tmp directory since it not only includes those empty files but also temporary cached files which shouldnt be indexed at all!

So I try to write a .gitignore file which should ignore everything in /app/tmp but not empty files, here's my not working attempt:

```
#.gitignore in cakephp root
/app/tmp
!/app/tmp/logs/empty
!/app/tmp/sessions/empty
!/app/tmp/tests/empty
!/app/tmp/cache/models/empty
!/app/tmp/cache/persistent/empty
!/app/tmp/cache/views/empty
```

What am I missing? Is .gitignore maybe not cappable to so something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually tried this? You mention nowhere whether this works or not.

Comment: Heh, I mention it: "here's my not working attempt:" Edit: Oh I see, I forgot to mention what happened by using this .ignore file: the complete /app/tmp/ directory is not being commited!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add `!empty` to the root `.gitignore`? Git will apply ignore rules recursively, from repo root to the end-directory. So if you have `!empty` in root ignore rules, it will be applied everywhere without any repeatitions.

The problem may be if `app/tmp` contains only ignored file (with any folding level). In this case git will not index `app/tmp` as it indexes only actualy existing *files*.

Comment: didnt worked; I tried it like this in my gitignore file: `!empty` and the second line `/app/tmp`. There is an empty file in /app/tmp/cache/persistent, yet, the whole directory, /app/tmp is getting deleted : (